# chaquopy Does not add folder to phone

Tags: python, java, android, android-studio, chaquopy

In my project, I tried to write a code using Chaquopy to add a folder to Android when running the program. Everything is correct and it does not give any error but nothing is added.

here is my `MainActivity` code

```
package com.example.use_chaquopy;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.chaquo.python.Python;
import com.chaquo.python.android.AndroidPlatform;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Context context = this;
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView t1 = findViewById(R.id.t);
        if (! Python.isStarted()) {
            Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(context));
        }
        if (Python.isStarted()) {
            t1.setText("python is start");
        }
    }
}
```

and this id `python` script

```
import os

os.mkdir("loolmkkukj")
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Java code isn't actually running any Python script. Check the [Chaquopy documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/java.html) for examples of how to do that.

Also, your script won't work, because on Android, the current directory is usually the root directory, which is unwritable by normal apps. Instead, as described [here](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#os), you should write to `os.environ["HOME"]`, which is set to your app's internal storage directory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...
and Thank a lot for answering users' questions about what you made.
I just have a very small question, do I have to write this code to create a folder?
import os

os.environ["HOME"]
os.mkdir("loolmkkukj")

Comment: Do something like this: `os.mkdir(f"{os.environ['HOME']}/loolmkkukj")`