# Why Android Studio can't run projects written with chaquopy?

Tags: python, java, android, android-studio, chaquopy

My project is completely written under the rules of chquopy, but it does not run.
what is my problem?

this is my `MainActivity` code:

```
package com.example.use_chaquopy;

import static com.chaquo.python.Python.getInstance;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.chaquo.python.PyObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        PyObject sys = getInstance().getModule("sys");
        sys.get("maxsize").toLong();
        sys.get("version").toString();
        sys.callAttr("is_finalizing").toBoolean();
    }
}
```

and this is `build.gradle(:app)` code:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.chaquo.python'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.use_chaquopy"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
        }

        sourceSets{
            main{
                python.srcDir "src/main/python"
            }
        }

        python {
            buildPython "C:/Users/Digital/New folder/yes.exe"
            pyc {
                src false
            }
        }

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

`build.gradle(project_name)`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.chaquo.python' version '11.0.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`setting.gradle`:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        pluginManagement {
            repositories {
                maven { url "https://chaquo.com/maven" }
            }
        }
    }
}

rootProject.name = "use_Chaquopy"
include ':app'
```

and finaly my `python` script code (program uses exe version):

```
import sys
sys.maxsize
sys.version
sys.is_finalizing()
```

just like what chaquopy say

what's the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not run"? What are you expecting to happen, and what exactly did happen? If you got an error message, please edit your question to include it. And if your app crashed, you can find the stack trace by following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174).

Comment: program crashes but gives no error anywhere @mhsmith

Comment: See my previous comment for how to find the error. The only possible problem I can see is that you haven't included a call to `Python.start`, as you did in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71293396).